# Protected access modifier

Tags: java, protected

[JLS 6.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2) gives us the following restriction for the package-access of protected members.

> A protected member or constructor of an object may be accessed from
>   outside the package in which it is declared only by code that is
>   responsible for the implementation of that object.

What did they mean responsible for implementation. Couldn't you get an example?

Answer (score 4):

It means that you can't access a protected super-class member of a different instance of the same class.

```
package one;
public class A {protected int b;}

package two;
public class B extends A {

    public void someMethod (A other)
    {
        b = 5; // allowed
        other.b = 5; // not allowed
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not correct. Class-code may access protected fields of all instances

Comment: @DThought class code may access any fields of its own class (even private), but access to protected fields of a super-class that belongs to a different package can only be done for the same instance.

Comment: Did you actually try the example you've given? I've did, and eclipse lets me happily modify my other.test field, wich is a protected field in the superclass.

AFAIK the package a class is contained in is only relevant for the "default" access modifier

Comment: @DThought I did, and I fixed my code sample (changed the method signature).

Comment: @DThought The package a class is contained in is relevant here, since package private access is stronger than protected access. This means that protected behaves exactly as package private if both classes are in the same package.

Comment: Ah! The package isn't of relevance at all for your case - you can't access the field b as it does belong to a different class.

B can't access fields of class A - no mater what instance.

if it were 

someMethod (B other) { other.b=5 } ; 

the code would compile happily, as you can access a protected field that has been defined in a superclass even in a subclass.